# Determine this set is convex or not.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I have to determine the following set is convex or not.

$$S=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_{++} : \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \ge 1\},$$
where $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}= \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n) : x_1,\ldots, x_n > 0\}$.

I think $S$ is not convex set then I have tried to find some counterexamples but they turned out to be false.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to actually look at this region for $n=1,2,3$? You should make use of your visual intuition whenever possible, because convexity is usually pretty easy to tell by eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma**  Assume $f$ is a concave function defined in some convex subset $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Then for every $c$ the set
$$A=\{x\in C| f(x)\geq c\}$$
is convex.

**Proof**  If $x,y\in A$, then for $0\leq\lambda\leq 1$ the point $\lambda x+(1-\lambda y)\in C$ because $C$ is convex. Moreover, since $f$ is concave,
$$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\geq \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)\geq c$$
Hence the point $\lambda x+(1-\lambda y)\in C$ is also in $A$, so $A$ is convex. Q.E.D

Put $C=\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$, and define
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log x_i\quad (x\in C)$$
Then the set $S$ in the given question is
$$S=\{x\in C| f(x)\geq 0\}$$

For every $1\leq i\leq n$, the function $f_i(x)=\log x_i$ is concave on $C$, hence $f$ is also concave, as a sum of concave functions. It follows from the Lemma that $S$ is convex.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @amWhy I am afraid that if too-lofty standards are enforced, put in place, and used to annoy people, this site will vanish.

Answer (score 2):

First consider the case when $n=2$. Consider a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = 1/x$ with $\mathbf{dom} f = \mathbb{R}_{++}$. Then, notice that

\begin{align}
  S
  &= \{ (x_{1}, x_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}_{++}: x_{1}x_{2} \geq 1\}
  \\
  &= \{ (x, t) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}_{++}: xt \geq 1\}
  \\
  &= \{ (x, t) : x \in \mathbf{dom} f, t \geq f(x) \}
  \\
  &= \mathrm{epigraph}(f).
\end{align}
Since $f$ is convex on $\mathbf{dom} f$, its epigraph is convex and therefore the set $S$ is convex.

Can you generalize the above argument to general $n$?

Comment: I think, let $f(x)= \dfrac{1}{x_1 \ldots x_{n-1}}$, but I have problem in proving f is convex.

Comment: To show that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x_{1}\dots x_{n-1}}$ is convex, first fix any $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}_{++}$. Let $v_{x} = [1/x_{1} 1/x_{2} \dots 1/x_{n-1}]^{\mathsf{T}} \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Then,  notice that $\nabla^{2} f(x) = 1/x (v_{x} v_{x}^{\mathsf{T}} + \mathrm{diag}(1/x_{1}^{2}, \dots, 1/x_{n-1}^{2})$ is positive definite, and so $f$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

Comment: Ok I will try, thank you.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.